# Cross Join When Building Predicate for QueryDSL

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl, cross-join

I am using Query DSL with Spring Data Jpa with `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`

I have the following Entities;

```
@Table(name="a_table")
@Entity
public class A {

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
     private B b;
}

@Table(name="b_table")
@Entity
public class B {

     @Column(...)
     private String name;
}
```

When I build the `Predicate` to pass into my Repository I do something like this.

```
QA qa = QA.a;
BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();       
for(String name : strings) {
    BooleanExpression b_name_eq= qa.b.name.eq(name);
    BooleanExpression some_other_expression = ...;
    booleanBuilder.or(ExpressionUtils.and(b_name_eq, some_other_expression));
}
return booleanBuilder.getValue();
```

Which results in a Query like the following

```
select ... , ... , ...
from a_table at
cross join b_table bt  
where at.b_id=bt.id 
and (bt.name=? and some_other_expression or bt.name=? and some_other_expression or ...)
```

My question is can I control when generating my Predicate to use a Join other than cross join? Because cross Join is considered by some experts to be slow. I know I can do this easily by `JPAQuery` but we are not using it. Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I wish somebody had an answer to this. I just encountered it with my app. It seems like one of those Hibernate+JPA "can't there from here" complete nonsense issues that make me wish I didn't have to use it. Do it the nice way, get a stupid join plan. Write the join plan yourself, lose pagination. WTF.

Comment: Please share the generated JPQL query and the Hibernate version used. It appears the cross join is added by Hibernate. I also think Hibernate only does so when the association is mapped as non-optional. However in old versions of Hibernate there have been some quirks where OneToOne associations were always pretty much treated non optional.